# Replacing individual characters in a string, with a variable string?

Tags: c#, string, methods

Asked a previous question that didn't really ask what I wanted to know, and wasn't very thought out so here's a new question, I want to replace specific characters in a user inputted string with different characters, as in replace all instances of "a" with "w". I need to declare a method that will make this work. I'm stuck because I don't know what to tell it to do. I know I want it to find the characters and replace them, but I'm not sure how to go about it. This is what I have so far:

```
public static void Encrypt(string args)
{


} 

public static void Decrypt(string args)
{


}

static void Main(string[] args)
{

     Console.WriteLine("Enter string to be encrypted or decrypted");
     string words = Console.ReadLine();
     Console.WriteLine("Enter 1 to encrypt or enter 2 to decrypt");
     string EnOrDec = Console.ReadLine();
     int answer = Convert.ToInt16(EnOrDec);
     if (answer == 1)
     {
         Encrypt(words);                
     }
     if (answer == 2)
     {
         Decrypt(words);
     }

   }
}
```

I tried using the replace method found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx but it gave me errors and I'm not sure that's what I want anyways. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please add your code where you tried using the `Replace` method.

Comment: Why are you using this line: `int answer = Convert.ToInt16(EnOrDec);` did you want an `Int16`/`short` or an `Int32`/`int` ?

Comment: The code you have posted shows no effort to fix the problem, also note this sounds more like encoding or obfuscation than encryption

Comment: I you don't know what you want, how are we supposed to know it? Oh, and please do not call a method that is only replacing one character by another "Encrypt".

Comment: The problem with this approach is `we like apples` becomes `we like wpples` when "encrypted" and `ae like apples` when "decrypted". It's not symmetrical. A slightly better approach would be to convert the string to character codes and shift them individually.

Comment: I know it's not actually encryption thats just what the assignment calls it, I'll add in the code I tried that didn't work to the original question

Comment: How do I convert them to character codes? I think that's what I want @DanWilson

Answer (score 0):

Try this sample code:

```
      string text = "ABCABCABCABC";
      text=text.Replace("A", "W");
```

Comment: Ok I ran that and it worked. I think I understand it now let me rewrite it and see if that works.

Comment: I tried to put this in via method like so: 
public void Encrypt(string args)
        {
            words = words.Replace("A", "W");

        }


But it gives me errors with the {} brackets here's the full code https://dotnetfiddle.net/5hrjjT

Comment: Try this: public void Encrypt(string args) { args= args.Replace("A", "W"); }

Comment: I tried that I'm still getting the bracket errors. I double checked for extra brackets and there aren't any. https://dotnetfiddle.net/hN09zs

Comment: The Encrypt method has to stay out of the Main... https://dotnetfiddle.net/cPM5yW

Comment: Oh duh. Okay so this is what I have now, it's not giving me an error in visual studio but when I run it, it just outputs WBCWBCWBCWBC. Is what I've done not okay? https://dotnetfiddle.net/ncSYSb

Comment: Encrypt must be static: public static void Encrypt(string args)

Comment: I did that but it doesn't change the output of WBCWBCWBCWBC. I can't figure out why it's outputting that.

Comment: args must be a ref: Encrypt public static void (ref string args) and when you call the method you need write: Encrypt(ref words);

Comment: No errors but same output. It's not writing anything but the WBC. It's not even asking the questions

Comment: I deleted all the arguments and it's outputting the same thing.

Comment: Copy and pasted into a new project and it worked, but only replaced the first letter, meaning I typed Hello and it output Dello

Answer (score 0):

```
words.Replace("a", "w")
```

will yield the desired `String`. A method to do this would look like

```
public String myReplace(input, what, withWhat) {
    return input.Replace(what, withWhat);
}
```

and you can call it like this:

```
myReplace(words, "a", "w")
```

If you intend to do this manually, then you can do something like this:

```
public String myReplace(input, what, withWhat) {
   while (input.indexOf(what) >= 0) {
       input = input.Substring(0, input.IndexOf(what)) + withWhat + input.Substring(input.IndexOf(what) + what.length);
   }
   return input;
}
```